# Are any properties of a matrix changed when you take its transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality, transpose

I'm trying to construct a pretty basic proof. The proof will show that the column vectors of an orthogonal matrix form an orthonormal set. We can assume that this is a 3x3, orthogonal matrix. I know this proof is done over and over, but my professor wants to see it without any theorems invoked whatsoever and I'm having a lot of fun with it. I'm getting stuck though and I think I could solve it if I could show that no properties of a matrix were changed when taking its transpose, however, I can't seem to be able to show this or even find if this is true. Can anyone help me out with this? Either the proof that no properties of the matrix are changed or the proof, without theorems, that the column vectors form an orthonormal set? Thanks for the help in advance gang.

Comment: You will definitely have to be more specific about what properties you care about. For example, when you take a transpose you may (if it's not n by n) change the domain of the function represented by the matrix.

Comment: Yeah, that's weak on my part, hold on; I need to edit the question. I left out some pretty important details. I've been working on this a few days and seem to just assume that everyone knows as much about the problem as I do.

Comment: Hmm.. Every matrix is similar to its transpose, so there are a lot of properties preserved

Comment: Yeah! particularly all of the ones addressed in the second half of a second-year linear algebra class. I just want to finish the proof on the transpose and claim it applies to the original matrix

Comment: Wait a second. What's exactly your definition of orthogonal matrix? I think I have the proof you need

Comment: "A nonsingular matrix P is orthogonal if P<sup>-1</sup> = P<sup>T</sup>"

sorry, I don't know how to use superscripts in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, every orthogonal matrix $P$ satisfies $P^TP=PP^T=I$.

In particular, if we call $p_1,\dots,p_n$ the columns of $P$, we get from $P^TP=I$ that $p_i^Tp_j = 0$ if $i\ne j$ and $p_i^Tp_i=1$ for every $i$. This means that the columns form a orthonormal set(basis).

Notice that you can do the same for rows with the formula $PP^T=I$.

Comment: That's the one, you solved it about a thousand times more succinctly that I was going to, but you nailed it. Thanks Exodd; you're a legend in your own time.